# Stop on hover on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

Alright so I am trying to get an on hover function to work where it the div that I am on will pause on hover and start up again when my mouse has left the hover area. Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
 <div id="slideshow">
 <div>
 <iframe width="400"; " height="290"; src="www.google.com"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div>
 <iframe width="400"; " height="290"; src="www.google.com"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div>
 <iframe width="400"; " height="290"; src="www.google.com"></iframe>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
 #slideshow {  
position: relative; 
width: 340px; 
height: 340px; 
padding: 1px; 
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
position: relative; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
bottom: 0px; 
}

</style>
```

jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
$("#slideshow").hover(function () { 
this.stop();
}, function () {
this.start();
});

setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  10500);

</script>
```

any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated. I have tried a few different things that haven't worked such as .hover(), .stop(), and clearInterval(). I think my execution is all wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Umm..._ You might want to make sure everything is valid before continuing! **Use W3 Validator**

Comment: @Olivr3000 I will check it out. But everything runs perfectly on my end. I just can't get it to stop on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You begin learn javascript. you must read document  and understand function to use api like jquery and other javascript library. please understand function and use it this.start() and this.stop() where you define it?

Answer (score 0):

You can **achieve your goal using clearInterval on mouseenter event.**
Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>       
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>slideshow</title>
        <style>
             #slideshow {  
                position: relative; 
                width: 400px;
                height: 290px;              
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
            }
            #slideshow iframe { 
                position: absolute; 
                top: 0px; 
                left: 0px;      
                height: 100%;   /* fit to parent */
                width: 100%;    
                display: none;      
            }
            #slideshow iframe:first-child{display:block;} /*Initially display  
                                                           the first iframe */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">
                <iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe> 
<!-- You cannot use www.google.com. The reason for this is, 
that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. 
This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted
 on the same domain as the parent page. -->

                <iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
                <iframe src="http://www.example.com></iframe>
        </div>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            myinterval = doAnimation(); // Start the animation

            $('#slideshow').on({                    
                mouseenter: function(e){
                    clearInterval(myinterval); //stop animation
                  },
                mouseleave: function(e){      //restart animation 
                    myinterval = doAnimation();   
                  }
            });

          // Animate the slideshow.
            function doAnimation(){
                return setInterval(function(){
                    $('#slideshow :first-child')
                        .fadeOut()
                        .next('iframe')
                        .fadeIn()
                        .end()
                        .appendTo('#slideshow');
                    }, 2000);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```